# Does the color depth on terminal services have an effect on the experience

Tags: windows-xp, terminal-services, remote-desktop

I connect to a remote computer using mstsc on a slow connection. Now I have set the settings in the experience tab to the lowest. I was wondering if reducing the color depth will improve my experience any further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will.  If you go from 16 bit (65535 or thousands) color to 8 bit (256 or hundreds) color, that halves the amount of data that terminal services needs to transmit in the image.  Eight bit color does look pretty bad.

Comment: ... In addition, should be made clear - talking about the option inside mstsc / remote desktop connection and not manually changing the option when connected.

Comment: Yes I am talking about setting the option from my mstsc client and not on the remote computer